# Add transaction rid, generated timestamp or any other uuid to each imported file from S3/directory

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

in the Foundry Data Connection app, I can apply Transformers to the files ingested from S3 or any other Filesystem like source.

Is there any Transformer available to add an identifier (e.g. current transaction_rid, a generated timestamp when the ingestion started, or a uuid) to all filenames?

We have a source that provides numbered files, that get deleted automatically and replaced with new version, but we want to leverage an APPEND/UPDATE transaction type in the ingestion.

Thanks

Comment: Did I understand you correctly, you want to change the filenames of the files you are ingesting based on an identifier? Or are you talking about the output files of your transform?

Comment: Yes, I would like to add an identifier to each ingested file. Ideally before the file extension. E.g. file_001.csv -> file_001_{transactionrid}.csv or file_001_{timestamp}.csv